# Attempted to call function from namespace

Tags: php, symfony

Got this error, and don't understand it.. Thanks in advance for your help :D

Info :
- Symfony 3
- Ubuntu 15.x

```
Attempted to call function "mcrypt_create_iv" from namespace "AppBundle\Controller".
```

Use and class :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Logs;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;


class FileController extends Controller
{
```

My function :

```
    protected function encrypt ($payload, $key) {
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $crypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $payload, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $combo = $iv . $crypt;
    $garble = base64_encode($iv . $crypt);
    return $garble;
}
```

And where i call it :

```
    public function getPrivateDirectoryAction($returnPath = false, Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if ($request->request->get('path') != null){
        $fullPath = $request->request->get('path');
    } else {
        if($returnPath){
            $fullPath = $returnPath;
        } else {
            $path = $this->getUser()->getPath();
            $dir = $this->ftpDirectory;
            $fullPath = $dir.$path;
        }
    }
    $finder = new Finder();
    $files = $finder->in($fullPath);
    $this->generateLogAction($user, $fullPath, 'null', 'access');

    $files = iterator_to_array($files->getIterator());

    foreach($files as $key => $value) {
        $value->path_crypted = $this->encrypt($value->getPath(), 'secret') . '||' . $this->encrypt($value->getBasename() , 'secret');
    }

    return $this->render('File/index.html.twig', array(
        'files' => $files,
        'path' => $fullPath

    ));
}
```

(It's in the same class..)

If someone can help me, explain how you did with easy word please. My english is realy bad :D

Edit :

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache

mcrypt support  enabled
mcrypt_filter support   enabled
Version 2.5.8
```

Comment: Do you have the mcrypt extension (e.g. php5-mcrypt) installed and enabled?

Comment: Installed and enabled ^^

Comment: are you sure? `php -m` to check

Comment: Yes i am :D @Federico

Comment: can you post the output of `php -m`?

Comment: can you check the correct lib enabled via php.info also? try with the symfony profiler (something like `http://<your-host>/app_dev.php/_profiler/phpinfo`)

Comment: Updated my post @DevDonkey

Comment: @FauconnierLucas When in namespace you should call global scope using ``\`` i.e. you should use `\mcrypt_create_iv`, `\mcrypt_encrypt`, etc

Comment: @Leri Already tryed. Didn't work :/

Comment: Did you solve it?